# How do I begin this question and how to is the -ve number found?

Tags: c++

Question 1: You are required to create a linked list class. A single node/bead for the linked list must be able to hold a single hexadecimal digit, stored within an integer type. The linked list must thus be able to store a number, consisting of all of the connected hexadecimal digit elements. You are to assume that the number representation is two's complement and that the least significant digit is at the head.

Your linked list implementation should have, a struct for the node/bead, an appropriate constructor and destructor, and a function that allows you to add digits to the head of the list.  What you are required to create are:

1.a member function, called absolute, that will return an integer variable of the decimal equivalent of the absolute value (meaning positive) equivalent of the stored number in the linked list.

2.a main file which will populate different instances of your linked list class with different numbers, and output to the console, the result of your absolute function. You should include both a test with a positive number stored and one with a negative number stored, to ascertain that your linked list absolute member function works as expected. A third test, which will catch the result of a thrown exception when the linked list is empty should also be done.

Question 2: You should repeat question 1, however, instead of creating your own linked list, you are to use the STL linked list implementation, and iterators. The absolute function should be a regular global function that takes your linked list as an argument/parameter.

This is to be coded in c++

```
    struct Node {
        int digit;
        Node* next;
    };

    class hexDigits {
    private:
        Node* head, * tail;

    public:
    hexDigits() {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }

    void add_node(int n) {
        Node* tmp = new Node;
        tmp->digit = n;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = tmp;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }

    void placementDigit(int n) {
        Node *tmp = new Node;
        tmp->digit = n;
        tmp->next = head;
        head = tmp;
    }

    void display() {
        Node *tmp = head;
        unsigned int count = 0;
        while (tmp != NULL) {
            std::cout << "Item " << count << ": "
                << tmp->digit << std::endl;
            tmp = tmp->next;
            count++;
        }
    }

    unsigned int size() {
        unsigned int count = 0;
        Node *tmp = head;
        while (tmp != NULL) {
            ++count;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        return count;
    }

    unsigned int absolute() {
        unsigned int exp = 0;
        unsigned int total = 0;
        int x = 0;
        Node*tmp = head;
        while (tmp != NULL) {
            total = (tmp->digit * pow(16, exp)) + total;
            tmp = tmp->next;
            exp++;
        }
        return total;
    }
};

int main() {
    hexDigits h;

//Test case #1

    h.placementDigit(2);
    h.placementDigit(3);
    h.placementDigit(11);
    h.placementDigit(5);

    h.display();

    cout << "Decimal Representation : "<< h.absolute() << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

This is code I've done but I am unsure of how to get the -ve hex numbers w.r.t the two's complement representation

Answer (score 0):

If you have already made a try, you should post the code here so we can help you. If you haven't, I suggest you try it and then post here if you get stuck.

I'm gonna assume you know the theory behind the questions you were given, and that your only problem is the implementation in C. So, here are some useful links:

First of all, you should learn how classes work in C++. [Here's](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm) a link that might give you some insight. Then, you can try to create a linked list class. [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus-program-to-implement-singly-linked-list) might help you with that. Also, one of the questions asks you to create a member function, so [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_class_member_functions.htm) might be helpful. Finally, you might have to work with binary operations, so [here's](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm) some information about operators in C++.

Good luck!